# How to use User input to form Canvas Shapes

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Need User to pick 5 spots withing canvas to form shape

New to canvas and javascript, been looking online on how to form shapes using canvas etc. I haven't been able to find how to incorporate user input in order to form shapes.

Any help / suggestions on what or where I should look are also helpful

Comment: Use a click event handler on the canvas

Comment: check this: https://codepen.io/chrisjaime/pen/lcEpn, it shows coordinates in canvas on mouse click.